# Improve db performance for search mongodb

Tags: mongodb, database-performance

I have a users document which can have:
firstName, lastName, displayName, email
something like that:

```
{firstName:"Niv", lastName:"Sap Josh", displayName:"Some Company/Sales/Account Manager/Niv Sap Josh", email:"niv@gmail.com"}
```

I want the search to be responsive to user's typing.
for example by searching "niv sa" or "spas jo" or "sales niv sa" or "sap josh ni" etc..
I don't want to use regex, my db is pretty big (about 100K documents)

I currently have the following strategy:
Index on an array field that contains the following:
Full name - first name + last name
Reverse full name: last name + first name (to support search by last name first)
username
email address
Text index on the job path field.
The performance is not so good - takes around 300 ms for one user search.
Any ideas or best practices to try and improve the search?
Thanks

Comment: What kind of index did you create? did you use text index on those fields? I'm not sure whether it will be faster than 300ms but I'm pretty sure it worths a shot if you didn't try it yet : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use ElasticSearch setup for your needs.
We did have some similar issues on few projects with MongoDB and MariaDB in the past, and the only option in both cases was to add ElasticSearch and use it for full-text search instead. Last time we had something about 10m+ customers and used search by a lot of fields (name, surname, invoice address, delivery address, email, ERP code, etc.). And it was like hell for MariaDB. But with ElasticSearch it works like a charm.

It really depends on the app and platform you are using, but most of platforms/frameworks already have libraries/packages for elasticsearch already. So it shouldn't be a problem to get 1 ElasticSearch cluster and try it out.
You can even use some packages which automatically index your mongo models.
Like this package for mongoose: https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic